# Elasticsearch: using sql server

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I 'm trying to make river-jdbc work in my elasticsearch on my windows machine. I have installed river-jdbc. And have also downloaded the driver for sql server. Now trying to configure it to use my sql server Express db.

When I inspect ES using elasticsearch-head i can see that jdbc river is installed. 
I am trying to configure it so that I can retrieve data from the tables.

```
Plugin{
name: jdbc-river
description: JDBC River
jvm: true
site: false
}
```

Any suggestion how to proceed next? I 'm referring to [this](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc/wiki/Quickstart) blog.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure as to where you are stuck.  But please take a note of this line in the page that you are referring -

If you're using a version of elasticsearch >= 0.90.0, you need to use at least version 2.2.0 of the river-jdbc plugin).